# Documented ffmpeg commands not recognized by ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to use options like, `ldash` and `http_opts`,  as the dash muxer docs describe but FFmpeg doesn't recognize them. I'm on the latest released version of ffmpeg, v4.2.2. I see the changes in the ffmpeg master branch but not in the v4.2 release branch. Does ffmpeg not recognize them because they haven't been released yet?

Here's the dash muxer docs for reference: https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#dash-2

Here's a minimal example command with uncut output:

```
Andrews-MacBook-Pro :: dev/test ‹master› » ffmpeg -re -i test.mp4 \                                   
-map 0 -map 0 -c:a libfdk_aac -c:v libx264 \
-b:v:0 800k -b:v:1 300k -s:v:1 320x170 -profile:v:1 baseline \
-profile:v:0 main -bf 1 \
-b_strategy 0 -ar:a:1 22050 \
-adaptation_sets "id=0,streams=v id=1,streams=a" \
-ldash 1 \
-f dash ./output/out.mpd

ffmpeg version 4.2.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.17)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.2.2_2 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libbluray --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librtmp --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-videotoolbox --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack
  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
  libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
Unrecognized option 'ldash'.
Error splitting the argument list: Option not found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, branches are cut from master every few months. `ldash` was committed on 15th Jan 2020, and the 4.2 series was cut on Aug 5 2019, so it will only be in master till 4.3 is cut. Micro versions rarely get feature updates.

Comment: Hey @Gyan, thanks for your response! I haven't been able to find a documented release cadence for FFmpeg. Can you shed some light on when `4.3` might be cut?

Comment: Inside two months is my guess. There is no official release interval, it's typically every 3-6 months depending on development activity.

Comment: @agconti [FFmpeg Download](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html#releases) page says "Approximately every 6 months the FFmpeg project makes a new major release", but in reality it is every 6-9 months. FFmpeg 4.3 is late. Use master unless you need a certain API version.

Comment: Thanks for the info @llogan!